# Nice look of website as a link on social networks

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, api

How to make website look nice when it's embedded as link on social networks pages(at least at Facebook). Can' find any information on the subject matter. Does this require interaction with social networks api or something?

Especially  when it's not via share button, but just copy past of link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put custom markup in the `<head>` of your site to influence what shows up when the link is embedded on Facebook.

Here's an example:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

Check out the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters.

Answer (score 0):

Every social network has its own API specification while sharing the link. For e.g, twitter provides summary card with large feature while sharing the website or article. https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper `metadata` (e.g. `<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />`) to make your web page appear rich object in social media such as Facebook.

***Extracted from from [ogp.me](https://ogp.me)***

> The Open Graph protocol enables any web page to become a rich object in a social graph. For instance, this is used on Facebook to allow any web page to have the same functionality as any other object on Facebook.

While, the meta `name` can be different for different social media websites, for instance, Twitter has [Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview) for its tweets.

So you can use, [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview) and [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me) to leverage rich content preview.